# obj-c addiction function to NSString

Tags: objective-c, metaprogramming, implementation

I'm using a declaration of function that converts NSData into hexadecimal NSString

```
@implementation NSString (Hex)

+ (NSString*) hexStringWithData: (unsigned char*) data ofLength: (NSUInteger) len
{
    NSMutableString *tmp = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<len; i++)
        [tmp appendFormat:@"%02x", data[i]];

    return [NSString stringWithString:tmp];
}

@end
```

- What is name of this procedure?
  (I mean how is called this `@implementation` into/of class which I haven't defined and where is documentation ?)
- What purpose has `(Hex)` part of implementation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [class cateogry](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) that provides a way to add extra methods to existing classes without the need of subclassing. `Hex` is the name of this particular category because a single class can have multiple categories. Special consideration should be taken when creating categories because it is possible to override existing or future methods.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, is there a way how can I programmatically take care of existing category? Or is it only problem of unique method name? So the categories would be merged and function won't be overriden? Thanks

Comment: To be careful you can prefix each method with something such as your initials.